# PHP password_hash() shows some unusual behaviour? Maybe i'm wrong?

Tags: php, password-hash

I've seen some unusual behaviour with password_hash function, maybe i'm wrong but check this:

```
$var = password_hash(false, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 10]);
$var = password_hash(null, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 10]);
var_dump($var);
```

It returns hashed string like this:

```
string(60) "$2y$10$MCkQPQcCxL5.ERZ5pJRA.en/MolCwd015OcqNk2zh.ajpicLxONge"
```

In my opinion it should not return nothing but false?

Comment: Why? false and null probably get auto-casted into an empty string here - and empty strings _can_ be hashed. (`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` would be the md5 of an empty string, for example.)

Comment: An absent return value would have even more security implications than the hashed empty string.

Comment: Because you don't won't to store empty values in your database.

Comment: IMHO, it's your job as a dev to make sure the value is correct before you pass it to password_hash().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [blog](https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2015/03/security-issue-combining-bcrypt-with.html) you can see that false and NULL values are allowed in passwords and will generate hashes. If you change `false` or `null` to an empty string you will also see a hash generated with the leading byte returning the same result. You can test for leading null bytes easily:

```
$var = password_hash(null, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 10]);
var_dump($var);

var_dump(password_verify("\0", $var));
```

with the final `var_dump()` producing `bool(true)` showing the you did created a hash using a leading null byte in your password. This is the expected behavior of `password_hash()` as it will only [return NULL on an error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

So this really isn't an issue because no one uses NULL bytes in their passwords. It only becomes an issue when you try to "roll your own" cryptography and the string that you would normally pass wouldn't be a string at all.

Even if you try to set a NULL byte in the string, it is really just a string:

```
$hashed = password_hash('\0asdfghjkl', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 10]);
var_dump($hashed);

var_dump(password_verify("\0", $hashed));
```

Which returns `bool(false)` from the `password_verify()`.

**Bottom Line**

Unless you are trying to do something tricky, like pre-hashing your passwords, what you have discovered here is by design. No one enters anything other than strings as their passwords (you could just double-check the password, [but don't cleanse them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628418/cleansing-user-passwords), to make sure it is a string which would be considered wearing suspenders with a belt) and you should never run across a case where NULL bytes are entered.

Comment: `because no one uses NULL bytes in their passwords` except people who want to break your login `;-)`

Comment: That's right @Martin ;-) which is why I always wear suspenders with my belts!